# jQuery BlockUI not blocking <select>

Tags: javascript, ajax, blockui

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu be blocked while the ajax function populates the list, and then unblocking itself once it's done. Any idea why it's not working?

```
    <script src="/Common/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

            function handleMoreResults (responseObj) {
                $("#dimensionId").html(responseObj.DimensionValueListItem.map(function(item) {
                    return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionValueDisplayName)[0];
                }));
            }

            function getMoreData() 
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: GetDimensionValues,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $.blockUI();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        object = data;
                        handleMoreResults (data);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $.unblockUI();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8GnXZ/

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  How are you calling `getMoreData()`?

Comment: GetMoreData() is being called in the onchange function for the first dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('select').block({ 
                message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
                css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
            });
```

and place the block and unblock call in the global ajax methods

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

for more info see the docs here http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element